# Need to replace duplicates in file except if the line matches a pattern

Tags: bash, sed, awk

My questions is fairly simple. I have a file containing lines which are often duplicates of one another. My first attempt used awk: `cat /tmp/log |awk '!x[$0]++'|`.

That does the job perfectly except that I realized there was one line that I need to have duplicated.

So basically I need to remove all duplicates except for one that contains "Successful association". Even if it is a dupe.

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print the line if not seen before or it equals to the allowed duplicate:

```
awk '!x[$0]++ || ($0 ~ /Successful association/)' /tmp/log
```

Comment: Awesome, that was it. I can't believe I didn't know / find anything on using || in that matter. Thanks again!

Comment: +1, but `except for one that contains "Successful association"` implies the check should be `$0 ~ /Successful association/` rather than strict equality.  Or just: `!x[$0]++ || /Successful association/`